# Add markdown code tick to beginning and ending of a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I searched all forums but didn't find a suitable way to achieve this.

variable

```
result=multiline
string and 
other string
```

Want to convert it to

````
```result=multiline
string and 
other string```
````

means add 3 ticks at the beginning and 3 ticks at the end of the file.

I know it's possible through sed, but I think it's not working because of special characters for example tick.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what's the final value of the variable, can you echo it?

Comment: I'm very confused by your description. Is `result` a shell variable that contains a multiline string, or do you have some other variable whose value starts with "result=multiline...", or something else? Similarly, what is the final state you're trying to achieve? Note: you cannot have a variable name that contains backticks, so changing a `result` variable to have three backticks before its name doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I want to add ``` in the beginning and ``` at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping backticks with `\` helped.

`echo $result > result.txt`

`` echo "\`\`\`" | cat - result.txt > some-result.txt ``

`` echo "\`\`\`" >> markdown-result.txt ``

Comment: Simply `echo "\`\`\`$result\`\`\`"` seems like a less cluttered approach.